# ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource

Tags: database, oracle, unix, plsql, aix

I have a series of scripts running in parallel as a nohup on an AIX server hosting oracle 10g. These scripts are written by somebody else and are meant to be executed concurrently. All the scripts are performing updates on a table. I am getting the error,

> ORA-00060: deadlock detected while
> waiting for resource

As I googled for this, I found,
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_deadly_perpetual_embrace_locks.htm

Even though the scripts are performing updation on the same table concurrently, they are performing updates on different records of the table determined by the `WHERE` clause with no overlaps of records between them.

So would this have caused the error?.

Will this error happen regardless of where the updates are performed on a table?.

Should I avoid concurrent updates on a table at all times?.

Strangely I also found on the nohup.out log,
`PL/SQL successfully completed` after the above quoted error.

Does this mean that oracle has recovered from the deadlock and completed the updates successfully or Should I rerun those scripts serially?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can get deadlocks on more than just row locks, e.g. see [this](http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/deadlocks.html). The scripts may be competing for other resources, such as index blocks.

I've gotten around this in the past by engineering the parallelism in such a way that different instances are working on portions of the workload that are less likely to affect blocks that are close to each other; for example, for an update of a large table, instead of setting up the parallel slaves using something like `MOD(n,10)`, I'd use `TRUNC(n/10)` which mean that each slave worked on a contiguous set of data.

There are, of course, much better ways of splitting up a job for parallelism, e.g. [DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10577/d_parallel_ex.htm).

Not sure why you're getting "PL/SQL successfully completed", perhaps your scripts are handling the exception?

Answer (score 33):

I was recently struggling with a similar problem. It turned out that the database was missing indexes on foreign keys. That caused Oracle to lock many more records than required which quickly led to a deadlock during high concurrency.

Here is an excellent article with lots of good detail, suggestions, and details about how to fix a deadlock:
http://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/deadlocks.html#unindex_fk

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well.  I don't know the technical details of what was actually happening.  However, [in my situation](http://www.dashaun.com/2011/02/01/my-month-long-battle-with-ora-00060/), the root cause was that there was cascading deletes setup in the Oracle database and my JPA/Hibernate code was also trying to do the cascading delete calls.  So my advice is to make sure that you know exactly what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I was testing a function that had multiple `UPDATE` statements within `IF-ELSE` blocks.

I was testing all possible paths, so I reset the tables to their previous values with 'manual' `UPDATE` statements each time before running the function again.

I noticed that the issue would happen just after those `UPDATE` statements;

**I added a `COMMIT;` after the `UPDATE` statement I used to reset the tables and that solved the problem.**

So, caution, the problem was not the function itself...

Comment: this is an appealing suggestion, except I want the option to rollback later in my PL/SQL script. If I have already commited, I lose that possibility.